# Alternative to <use/> to avoid repeating ids when repeating Inline SVG

Tags: svg

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wAbMEVfb0Uv2VLnf?preview) example.

So lets say I have svg that I am including inline in HTML

```
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="col-sm-3">
        <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
          <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
          <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">___THIS_IS_A_VARIABLE__</text>
        </symbol>
        <use xlink:href="#circle" width="85"  height="85"/>
      </svg>
```

I have a slightly more complex use care where the inside of the `<symbol/>` is a complex path of a different scale than the  svg root viewbox so I need to use the `<symbol/>` to scale it to be full size.

I need to include a bunch of these in my html which I do via a for loop. Everything works find, but I am afraid I might introduce bugs in the future because in my html document I have multiple elements with the same id.

My questions:

- Is there a different way to use `<use/>` like with a css selector?
- Am I correct that repeating ids in inline SVG inside a html document is as bad as  repeating ids in a html document itself?
- Is there a better way to nest `viewbox` attributes to avoid `<use/>`?

Comment: Regarding the second question: Yes. An element inside SVG can be used by id in another SVG. When you select an element by id, the first found in DOM is retrieved

Comment: all ids must be unique on a page.

Comment: have you considered using transforms vs. changing viewbox?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of is to make the `id` dynamic. So in ther case of using angular it would be:

```
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="col-sm-3">
        <symbol [id]="circleId" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
          <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"></circle>
          <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">___THIS_IS_A_VARIABLE__</text>
        </symbol>
        <use [attr.xlink:href]="'#' + circleId" width="85"  height="85"/>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a Framework, native W3C Web Components can do the same:

If you don't/can't specify an id, generate one: `let id = "id" + new Date()/1;`

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg-shape id=1 text="red"></svg-shape>
<svg-shape id=2></svg-shape>
<svg-shape id=3 text="blue"></svg-shape>
<script>
  customElements.define('svg-shape', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let id = this.getAttribute("id");
      let text = this.hasAttribute("text") ? this.getAttribute("text") : "";
      this.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="col-sm-3">
        <symbol id="id${id}" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
          <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25" fill="white" stroke="${text}" stroke-width="2"></circle>
          <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy=".3em">${text}</text>
        </symbol>
        <use href="#id${id}" width="85"  height="85"/>
      </svg>`;
      this.onclick = (evt) => console.log('clicked', id);
    }
  });
</script>
```